# Can I override behavior of literal object construction?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I can override the `Object` function to customize it were I so inclined:

```
Object = function (Object) {
    return function() {
        var obj = Object.apply(Object, arguments);
        obj.myprop = 99;
        return obj;
    };
}(Object);

> Object({a:1})
  Object {a: 1, myprop: 99}
```

My question is if there's any way to do something similar to override the behavior of object construction when the object is specified as an object literal (in full cognizance of the potential horrible consequences):

```
> {a:1}
  Object {a: 1, myprop: 99}
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do here? Just digging into "how far can I push the spec", or are you actually trying to solve a problem and think this would be useful? (because you're right, it's horrible =)

Comment: It is for a particular type of binding framework I am playing with. I'm quite sure this is not possible, unless I want to hack a JS parser.

Comment: But then why wouldn't you just integrally change the Object.prototype? Every instance operates off of that and prototype values are shared by all instances (and you can then use an `Object.defineproperty("myprop", Object.prototype, { get: ..., set: ...})` with closure wrapped getter/setter to do everything you might want to do.

Comment: Thanks that's useful. It doesn't exactly address my use case, which as I said I think is a lost cause, but just for fun, consider that I am a base 2 guy and want to write my number literals in base 2, so that when I say `var o = {a: 111}` and then `print o.a` it prints 7, as if I had somehow magically run `parseInt(val, 2)` on all number-valued properties in newly created objects.

Comment: Hm, I'm fairly certain that kind of overloading can only be done at the implementation level, not the interpertation level. As far as I can see the spec does not demand numbers to be base 10, but the numerical resolution is in no way guaranteed to be accessible (nor does it even need to exist as clean functions) as far as a running script knows.